# What should be done with a "duplicate" question that is hard to find in a search?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46458/what-happens-to-individuals-when-they-die-in-middle-earth?lq=1) after searching the site with what I thought were logical and reasonable search terms and coming up empty.

It was then identified that my question is answered quite thoroughly in as an answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43757/significance-of-mortal-men).

Based on [this discussion in meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1702/are-questions-duplicate-if-they-share-a-topic-and-a-title-but-not-a-medium/1709#1709), I accept that the questions are duplicate but I doubt whether any future visitor to the site with the same question as mine would be able to find it with a reasonable search.  This is because the answer delves much deeper into the background than the original question asked.

So my question is what should be done.  I am happy to close my question but should I edit the duplicate question to reflect the scope of the answer so that future users would be able to find it?

Answer (score 10):

Your question as it is now, has been closed as a duplicate.  The site doesn't auto-delete questions closed as duplicates, so moving forward, anyone searching for terms in your question will get it as [a result](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=care+and+ritual+men).  Opening your question, then leads users to the question yours is marked as a duplicate of.

All this essentially is to take care of this problem you're talking about.  This topic now has 2 questions with different wording available to the site's search engine, so you've expanded the likelihood of future visitors finding it.

---

I'm not sure I understand your last paragraph.  Can you expand on what you mean by 'the scope of the answer'?

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't realize that the closed questions stayed in the search. Your answer addresses what I was getting at in the last paragraph.  Basically the original question asked a fairly narrow point about Tolken's men and dwarves but the answer covered the subject much more comprehensively.