# How to deal with a Post which has two questions in it and one of which may be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

The questions are following:

1. [How is The Wall bypassed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14829/how-is-the-wall-bypassed/)
2. [How did Gared (Night's Watch man) get back from behind The Wall?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/how-did-gared-nights-watch-man-get-back-from-behind-the-wall)

The first question is more general in nature while the second question was sort of tricky because:

1. It asks how did Gared get across the wall?
2. It asks if the person who returned actually was Gared?

My answer on the first question lists all the ways listed in the canon sources to get across the wall. While on second question, I just established the case that the person who returned was really Gared and then I linked my first answer to answer how did he get across the wall.

Right now, the second question has four close votes to be closed as duplicate of the first question. While the first question has two votes to be closed as duplicate of the second question.

So Given the nature of the two questions, my question here is:

*Should Question 2 be closed as duplicate of Question 1? Or should it be left open given the extra question in it which has nothing to do with Question 1?<sup>1</sup>*

According to [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1702/are-questions-duplicate-if-they-share-a-topic-and-a-title-but-not-a-medium?rq=1) meta post, if the answers aren't exactly duplicate, the questions aren't duplicate.

---

<sub>1. I have actually cast a close vote already. I would retract it of course if the community consensus is that it should be left open</sub>

Comment: As per your super-text: you don't need to retract your close vote, that's what community vetting is about. At worst, people can vote to leave open.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I spot a multi-question question *where one or more parts are already duplicates*, I generally do three things;

1) **Vote to close as "[Too Broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things)"**. Note that this is the normal action when two or more questions are posted as a single question. **The fact that one part is a dupe is actually irrelevant at this point**

2) **Comment to explain that multiple questions should be asked *as multiple questions***

3) Elaborate in the comment to **explain that at least one part of the question is already a duplicate.**

---

Assuming the non-duplicate part of the question is actually interesting/novel, once the question gets closed, I might go back in and edit out the non-duplicate part, turning it into a single question. I'll then vote to reopen.

If the OP rolls back the edit, I'll remove my vote to reopen and explain why.

Comment: The OP of the question was last seen in April and the Question was asked in 2011. It already has 9 answers. Is this course of action valid in these circumstances?

Comment: @Aegon - If it's an invalid post, it doesn't really matter how old it is. As far as editing is concerned, be **very careful** in editing questions that are already answered.

Comment: Exactly. As I alluded to in my last post, sometimes the edit is done clumsily. I think it's a Fitness SE question I'm thinking of where they asked two questions, two people gave upvoted answers that answered the first point and then a third person edited the question to only have the second point so that they could answer it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - That would be an inappropriate edit.

Comment: I thought the normal course of action for multiple questions was “too broad.”

Comment: @Adamant - Oh yeah. Duh.

Answer (score 4):

For a post with two questions, we generally bug the querent to phrase it as two questions and some people with use the "Close as Unclear as to what you're asking" reason. I agree with the first but not with the second.

I have seen others remove one of the questions to remove the duplicated bit, although that's much worse behavior in my opinion, particularly if some of the answers reference the removed bit.

Comment: OP was unfortunately last seen in April and the question has been around since 2011 so would bugging him for splitting the post into two be a fruitful course to follow here?