# How can we make this question on-topic? Should we, at all?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Yesterday, [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/163614/54887) was asked by a user.

"[Would the War of the Five Kings have occurred if Ned had refused Robert's request?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163614/would-the-war-of-the-five-kings-have-occurred-if-ned-had-refused-roberts-reques)"

---

The trouble was:

1. It was based on a hypothetical premise i.e. What if X?
2. It had two separate but related questions.

At first it was getting closed as (Primarily opinion based?) as it looked like it would be based on speculation.

Skooba and RichS made the case that an objective answer was possible.

> Given other pointers in the story, there is enough to give a "good
>   subjective" answer to this question. - **[Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57310/skooba)**

And

> I disagree that this is a speculative question. It has been answered
>   two different ways already, with both answers agreeing the war was
>   inevitable, and both answers providing info from the books. The whole
>   continent of Westeros was a dry powder keg on a hot day and all it
>   needed was a spark. Any spark would do. The war may have run one
>   course or another, but in the end, much that was would be left in
>   ashes.  - **[RichS](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/63201/richs)**

OTOH, other veteran users like Mooz and Paul argued that it was still speculative:

> we'll have to agree to disagree. If the OP were only asking if a war
>   would still happen I'd agree with you. As the question is currently
>   worded, the OP wants to know if the war would still happen and if Robb
>   would have declared himself KitN and march south. That's far more than
>   we can reasonably speculate on, imo. - **[Paul](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/66948/paul)**

and

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking
>   about a "what-if" scenario. - [**Mooz**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21267/m%C3%B6oz)

As to the other part, that it had two questions in it, We already [know such questions are to be considered Too-Broad](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10240/54887).

So what I am wondering is, is there any way to make this on-topic? One approach that comes to mind from Valorum's answer on linked meta question, I could remove the second question from the post and VTRO. But is it appropriate? Or should I just leave it as it is.

Comment: I haven't looked at this particular question in detail, but would like to note that "what-if" questions aren't *necessarily* POB or close-worthy ([example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/135535/31394)).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Agreed. The cited question in this post could be answered subjectively as there are enough pointers, as Skooba said, to provide an answer to the hypothetical scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After cropping out the second question, the post received four reopen votes. I cast the final vote and the post has now been reopened.

I suppose that was kind of the community consensus on this. If a post has multiple questions, VTC as too-broad. If the post is edited to be focused on one main question instead, it should be reopened.